# Azure Resourcement Management REST API for Azure Resource Health

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am new to this forum.

I am looking at the Microsoft documentation on the Azure resource health Rest Api at the link below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/reduce-troubleshooting-time-with-azure-resource-health/

However, when I deliberately stopped one of the Azure website resource under my subscription, the Api is still returning status code 200.

Does anyone have similar issue/experience? Thanks very much!

Comment: When you say you get status code 200, do you mean the status of the API call (e.g. https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubID>/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses?api-version=2015-01-01)?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri, that's a good question. In fact both of status codes of the API call as well as the json response content are status 200.

Comment: Hi Arthur, are you able to share your sample response here?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact call you are making to Resource Health, it's hard to answer the question. I am assuming from your question that you are making a call to get the health of a single resource.

When you stop your resource, Resource Health would return the status of the resource as `Unavailable`, it wouldn't throw an error. However, it takes around **10-12 minutes** for the change in health status to reflect.

It would be more helpful if you could share your response though.